# Loop over multiple variables in Puppet

Tags: puppet

In Puppet, I made my own module that adds administrator accounts to our management servers.

```
class admins::add_admin($username, $userkey) {

$username.each |String $username| {
  file { "/home/${username}":
    ensure => directory,
    mode   => '0750',
    owner => $username,
  }
  user { $username:
    ensure => present,
    shell => '/bin/bash',
  }
  ssh_authorized_key { $username:
    ensure => present,
    user => $username,
    type => 'ssh-rsa',
    key => $userkey,
  }
}
}
```

$username is an array of the desired usernames and $userkeys is an array of the ssh keys.

When the each loop is run, the users are created accordingly, however the keys are the same for every user (which is logical, because I don't have functionality yet to iterate over the userkeys).

What I want is that this Puppet module iterates over two arrays, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
class admins::add_admin (
  Array[Hash[String, String]] $users_data = [], # declare data type and defaults
) {
  $users_data.each |Hash $user| {
    $username = $user['username']
    $userkey  = $user['userkey']

    file { "/home/${username}":
      ensure => directory,
      mode   => '0750',
      owner => $username,
    }
    user { $username:
      ensure => present,
      shell => '/bin/bash',
    }
    ssh_authorized_key { $username:
      ensure => present,
      user => $username,
      type => 'ssh-rsa',
      key => $userkey,
    }
  }
}
```

And then you'd pass data in that looks like this:

```
class { 'admins::add_admin':
  users_data => [
    {
      'username' => 'bill',
      'userkey'  => 'keydata1',
    },
    {
      'username' => 'ted',
      'userkey'  => 'keydata2',
    },
  ]
}
```

I think it is much better here to restructure your input data than try to deal with two arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately passing data with the supplied class doesn't seem to fill the fields. However when I declare them in the admin::add_admin class definition it does work. What am I missing here? How exactly should I supply the data to the admins:add_admin class from init.pp?

Comment: That's a bigger question than I can answer here in a comment, and I would need to see your code. You're welcome to ask a new question.

Comment: @user10075632 Hash is definitely the data type for this situation. Also let us not forget the essential third user `rufus`. Agree that your comment is a new question.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I think if the `$users_data` was a hash with the `username` as the key and the `userkey` as the value it might be cleaner. You could `$users_data.each |String $username, String $userkey|` and I think the data structure would be leaner too.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I think you're right that a key as the username is probably a more natural structure. What if the OP later wants to add other fields?

Comment: Usually nested hash where the key is the `username` and the value is a hash of kv pairs where one would be `userkey: keydata1`. Then you have `$users_data.each |String $username, Hash $userdata|` and `key => $userdata['userkey']`.